# Tracking Outbound links in Google Analytics not repoting

Tags: hyperlink, google-analytics, outbound

I have used the information on this site and at this page

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

to add tracking on my outbound links (pictures and texts) at this page

http://virginialidar.com/index-2.html

I am trying to view them in Google Analytics (Reporting > Behavior > Events > Overview) but no clicks are showing up. I have visited the site and clicked the links may times to test. It has been about 72 hours since I added the code.

Can someone view source at http://virginialidar.com/index-2.html and see what I am doing wrong? I think it may be the image links

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've copied the "smart" quotes instead of the straight quotes. You currently have:

```
 onclick=”trackOutboundLink(‘http://qcoherent.com/evaluation.html’); return false;"
```

When it should be...

```
 onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://qcoherent.com/evaluation.html'); return false;"
```

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the code.  Ill give analytics a day or two to see if it catches the outbound clicks then get back.

Comment: @user27239, you should be able to see the event fire in your Real-time reports.

Comment: Cannot see any evidence of outbound clicks on the URLS

Comment: I'm still seeing smart quotes on your page (look at the single quotes). You can test this via clicking a link and looking in the console... you'll see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`